# Prove two matrices are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let  $B$ be a  non-zero matrix in $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $B^2=0$. Prove $B$ is similar to \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.

**My attempt**: Let $T:\Bbb C^2\to \Bbb C^2$ such that $M(T)=B$. Then $T^2=0$. Hence I proved that $v,Tv$ is a basis of $\Bbb C^2$ where $v \notin \text{null} T$  such that $M(T)$ has desired form.

Now I know it's a simple question but I am having hard time finishing the argument, can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Your argument is fundamentally flawed: you are supposed to show is that **if** $B$ satisfies $B^2 = 0$, **then** $B$ is similar to the matrix
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}.
$$
What you have shown is the *converse* of this implication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline of Solution:** Because $B$ is non-zero, there exists a vector $v \in \Bbb C^2$ such that $Bv$ is non-zero. Argue that the vectors $v$ and $Bv$ are linearly independent, so that $\{v,Bv\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb C^2$. Show that the matrix of $B$ relative to this basis is
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},
$$
so that $B$ is indeed similar to this matrix.

---

By your argument: if $T$ denotes the transformation $T(x) = Bx$ and $\mathcal B = \{v,Bv\}$, then the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is $N$. Equivalently, if $P$ denotes the matrix whose columns are $v,Bv$, then
$$
N = P^{-1}BP,
$$
so that $N$ is similar to $B$.

Comment: I think I have written same steps. Infact my issue was how to write the last step in good language.

Comment: To me, it does not look like you did. It looks to me like you *assume* that $T$ is such that $M(T) = N$, which is the wrong way to start because this is what we are trying to prove.

Comment: No, we are given a matrix $B$ and I assumed $M(T)=B$. Then I showed by taking basis $v,Tv$ we can achieve desired matrix.

Comment: @Shady You're right, I misread your proof. That said, if you have the matrix $B$, I see no reason to introduce the transformation $T$.

Comment: @Shady I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're having trouble with, then. Is it specifically the step of showing that $B$ is similar to $N$?

Comment: Like I mentioned, I am having trouble writing the "closing statement". Because I feel leaving the argument to this point is incomplete.

Comment: @Shady Why do you feel that the argument is incomplete? What do you feel is missing?

Comment: It's because I am ending my proof with "$M(T)$ has desired form". but since question mentioned only matrices so I should somehow show $B=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} A$

Comment: @Shady see my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that might overkill:

$B^2 = 0$ implies $f(\lambda) = \lambda^2$ is an annihilating polynomial of $B$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $B$ is either $d(\lambda) = \lambda$ or $d(\lambda) = \lambda^2$. Because $B \neq 0$, we must then have $d(\lambda) = \lambda^2$. As an order $2$ matrix, this shows the characteristic polynomial (because minimal polynomial divides characteristic polynomial) of $B$ is $\varphi(\lambda) = \lambda^2$.

In summary, we derived $\varphi(\lambda) = d(\lambda) = \lambda^2$, which is sufficient to [conclude that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Characterization) $B$ is similar to an order $2$ companion matrix, which is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.